# Duplicate DB Entries on Double Request even after SELECT First

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, insert, duplicates

I am not sure if I have put right words in title to explain. But here it is.

Application: Coldfusion/MySQL

Problem exceptionally occurred during bad internet reception which triggered double requests before the first one completed. In result two database entries were made.

Application is only handling double request with a SELECT query first to check if there is already a same record in db. In that case old record is updated with an UPDATE statement. Otherwise an INSERT statement is used to insert a new record. The SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE are enclosed within CFTRANSACTION.

```
<cftransction>
    <cfquery></cfquery> //SELECT
    <cfif SELECT.found>
        <cfquery></cfquery> //UPDATE
    <cfelse>
        <cfquery></cfquery> //INSERT
    </cfif>
</cftransaction>
```

In most cases when there is some delay in two requests, it works fine. To reproduce the problem,

1. I first tried initiating two simultaneous requests via browser and it didn't trouble in many tries.
2. To make two requests quick, I used two post statements right after one on the page (it's an AJAX app). It also worked as expected as second request was only updating the previously entered record.
3. What I could do to make those two requests even quicker, I reached out at the server itself (where both the ColdFusion and MySQL are running) and opened the browser. Now one browser request with two post statements started frequent double entries.

Above code might insert two entries when the REQUEST.2 SELECT runs before REQUEST.1 INSERT. What could be possible solution on the server end?

Handling on the client side with disabling subsequent requests before the first request completes. but want to secure it on the server.

Comment: For the insert query, are you using `values`?

Comment: Instead of the SELECT .. INSERT approach have you looked at db options such as [REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html) or [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)?

Comment: @DanBracuk yes, I am using INSERT INTO (col1, col2) values ('val1','val2') right after checking for the same values with SELECT query first.

Comment: @Leigh I'll check those approaches as well, and get back. thank you.

Comment: Instead of the `values` approach, you could use the `select etc where not exists (something)` approach.

Comment: @DanBracuk you mean one query? as below
INSERT INTO TABLE (col1, col2) SELECTval1, val2 FROM TABLE 
it could do better I guess. but I also had to perform some other checks within ColdFusion before inserting. it's not an option

Comment: @Leigh thank you for your suggestion as well. I didn't know about REPLACE or INSERT with DUPLICATE KEY because I am not a database guy. I just tested REPLACE with my code and it actually worked. Only I had to put those columns combined in a UNIQUE index to work it out.

Comment: @KAR - You are welcome. Nice write up btw :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I used the solution porvided by @Leigh in comments to original question. Just answering to make it standout and what other things I had to do to actually use this solution.

> Instead of the SELECT .. INSERT approach have you looked at db options such as [REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html) or [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)? – Leigh

While both the solutions seemed good to solve the problem but REPLACE was more attractive as it only required me to change "INSERT" keyword in the queries with "REPLACE"

With a quick overview from the docs, REPLACE exactly replaces and works like INSERT statement but performs the purpose only when a row is found with duplicate PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE index.

1- As I required three columns to be unique in that sense which I was using in a WHERE clause with SELECT before inserting them. I had to add a UNIQUE index on those three columns before REPLACE could work to restrict duplicate rows.

2- If duplicate row found, REPLACE first deletes the old row and then inserts the new one. This process also could loose some values from other columns in the table. But in my application, these columns are updated on every REQUEST while the values for those are derived from other tables. So it was not problem for me as the data can be updated for the new row inserted.

Comment: After implementing with REPLACE, I remembered that if you use UNIQUE index on those columns combined, you can even use INSERT statement with application's TRY/CATCH exception handling. This will just not entertain the further duplicate requests and will just avoid giving any error unless you want in the CATCH block... But I am still using REPLACE which sure has its positive sides as the data from most recent REQUEST are used in the new row.

Answer (score 0):

The <cftransaction> will group together the select + insert/update queries but will not prevent a second+ request from executing, even from the same browser before the transaction is completely finished.

I have run into similar problems with the IE browser.  The user could spam-click the submit and IE would submit for each time the submit button was clicked.

The most common solution that I've employed is to disable the submit button after it is clicked, or replace (hide it) it with a message that says something like "please wait, submitting form...".  I've used JavaScript/jQuery for this task.  It isn't 100% effective and does depend on what browser is being used and if JavaScript is enabled.

Another option is to use a named <cflock> to make sure that code can only be executed as a batch.  This could cause a performance bottleneck if several people are using the form at the same time.  So, I would plan to use a session variable as part of the named <cflock> name.  That way the lock is unique to each user.

Below is a CF 11 example:

```
<cflock name="lckInsUpdt_#listFirst(session.sessionid, '.')#" timeout="300" throwontimeout="no" type="exclusive">
<cftransction>
    <cfquery></cfquery> //SELECT
    <cfif SELECT.found>
        <cfquery></cfquery> //UPDATE
    <cfelse>
        <cfquery></cfquery> //INSERT
    </cfif>
</cftransaction>
</cflock>
```

Comment: Thank you @ScottJibben. Yes, cftransaction is only there to handle purposely what it does. It's not there for multiple simultaneous requests.

Client side restriction is sure a last resort but it still is not perfect disabling buttons or disabling concurrent requests on browser/javascript.

CFLOCK is what I had much earlier before when I knew that CFLOCK must not be used on logic where the execution time has chances to increase. It should not be used on queries.